# Модель Вопрос-Ответ в django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-admin, django-model

Есть задача реализовать API обучающего сервиса на django. В админке должна быть возможность создавать Вопросы, на основе которых должны строиться тесты. Пользователи могут проходить тесты только один раз, при ответе на каждый вопрос сразу выводится результат верно/неверно с комментариями.

Суть вопроса: как правильно спроектировать модели для данного сервиса ? Вот мой вариант

```
    from django.db import models
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Question(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(verbose_name='Текст', max_length=250)
    num_right = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Кол-во правильных ответов')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Вопрос'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Вопросы'
        ordering = ['id']

class Answer(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text=models.CharField(verbose_name='Ответ', max_length=250)
    right = models.BooleanField(verbose_name='Правильный', default=False)

class Test(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(verbose_name='Тема', max_length=250)
    Questions = models.ManyToManyField(Question)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Тест'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Тесты'
        ordering = ['id']

class Topic(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(verbose_name='Название', max_length=250)
    theory = models.CharField(verbose_name='Теория', max_length=1000)
    tests = models.ManyToManyField(Test)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Тема'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Темы'
        ordering = ['id']

class Test_Result(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    test = models.ForeignKey(Test, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    result = models.CharField(verbose_name='Результат', max_length=300)
```

[image: создание вопроса в админке]
[image: создание ответа в админке]

При создании ответа можно создать вопрос, используя форму создания ответа. Хочу сделать обратное чтобы при создании вопроса можно было создавать ответы как создать поле в модели для этого ?

Предполагается, что при создании вопросов в админке к нему же можно будет добавить произвольное количество ответов и указать верные(один или несколько). Использую связь один ко многим т.е. один вопрос и множество ответов. Как определить поле в модели Question, чтобы при создании вопросов можно было создавать связанные с ним ответы прямо в админке ? При использовании связи многие ко многим есть поле для выбора объектов из связанной таблицы.
В целом буду рад любым советам по реализации API. Использую Django-rest-framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/intro/tutorial07/

Раздел Adding related objects. Классы admin.StackedInline и admin.TabularInline

[image: Вопрос с ответами]

Файл admin.py внутри приложения edu_service

```
from django.contrib import admin
from edu_service.models import *

class AnswersInLine(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Answer
    extra = 4

# Register your models here.
class QuestionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [AnswersInLine]

admin.site.register(Question, QuestionAdmin)
admin.site.register(Test)
admin.site.register(Topic)
admin.site.register(Answer)
```

Comment: похоже, это не ответ, а дополнение к вопросу. если так и есть, то дополните, пожалуйста, текст вопроса, нажав ссылку «править» ниже текста вопроса, а данный «ответ», пожалуйста, удалите

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, это ответ, возможно, я неясно выразился, но хотел реализовать именно это, то есть возможность создавать вопросы одновременно заполняя ответы к этому вопросу.  В остальном буду рад любым советам по проектированию API